# using HDMI out to serve multiple monitors

Tags: hdmi, dvi, sony-vaio

I have a Sony Viao laptop (VPCF1) with a single VGA out and a single HDMI out. I'd like to use the laptop in a "docking station" configuration with two DFP monitors and the laptop screen closed.

I bought an HDMI -> 2 DVI splitter, but it appears that the NVidia driver software can't detect the two DFP monitors attached-- it shows the same image on all three screens, and I can't find any way to make it treat the DFP as a separate monitor.

Am I out of luck here, or is it possible to run two digital displays (in a sort of twinview) configuration using a single HDMI out (ignoring the laptop display)?

thanks!

Comment: did that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The splitter you have is a simple mirroring splitter, its just dumbly sending the same signal to both displays.  it is not a dual monitor adapter.  AFAIK, there is no way to run two, independent displays from a single HDMI connector.  Depending on the VAIO's capabilities, you may be able to run one display via HDMI and one display via analog.  But you're not going to be able to run two digital displays from one HDMI.

Comment: Actually [you can](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital_se/). But it is too expensive, at least for me.