# can I get an HDMI splitter to use multiple monitors over HDMI?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, nvidia-geforce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [using HDMI out to serve multiple monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/171020/using-hdmi-out-to-serve-multiple-monitors)

I ordered a computer kit with an nVidia GTX 560 ti.  The graphics card has 2 DVI ports and 1 HDMI slot on it.  My question is whether it is possible to get an HDMI splitter and use multiple monitors connected over HDMI, or if I have to use the DVI ports for additional monitors.

Comment: What's wrong with a DVI to HDMI adapter?  (Keep in mind you can only run two monitors off this card anyway.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you really want.
Keep in mind that a HDMI splitter will give you the same picture on both monitors and register as a single attached monitor on your computer.
If you want it to be treated as two monitors where you can extend the desktop, you will need to get a DVI -> HDMI adapter (which isn't that expensive anyhow).  If you use the DVI -> HDMI, you can also mirror the screens from the OS